# Make mount not list "dummy" filesystems (like df)

Tags: mount

When using `mount` to simply list all mounted filesystems, is there some way to make it not list "dummy" filesystems?  That it, make it list only the filsystems that `df` does.

**EDIT**: by "dummy" I mean the filesystems which are included by `df` when you use the `--all` option, since that's what the `df` man page calls them.

Comment: You should probably specify a bit better, what exactly do you consider to be a "dummy" file system.

Comment: They're actually called "virtual" filesystems...

Comment: You should consider modifying your question, since the answer you accepted clearly states that you won't see neither `tmpfs` nor network file systems. Which are really not "dummy" by any reasonable meaning of the word (since users can place files there, if nothing else).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to use `lsblk -f`:

> lsblk  lists  information  about all available or the specified block devices.

This means, network shares (nfs, sshfs) or virtual file systems (dev,run,sys,proc et al) are  *not* displayed. Also, a `tmpfs` file system which is normally shown in `df -h` will *not* appear.

The `-f` option outputs info about file systems which includes the *mountpoint*.

on my machine for example, it lists:

```
NAME    FSTYPE          LABEL       UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
sda                                                                      
|-sda1  ext2            bootpar     ab2e48a8-5f1c-484e-a4a1-f8545e4b2019 /boot
|-sda2  swap            swappar     6e9f6e70-141a-417c-82a5-113a3d4c5a53 [SWAP]
`-sda3  ext4            homepar     52f7164d-fac7-4abe-bf78-71353fac7850 /home
sdb     isw_raid_member                                                  
`-md126 ext4            rootparraid 4275f5ba-8244-4039-9100-06afee678557 /
sdc     isw_raid_member                                                  
`-md126 ext4            rootparraid 4275f5ba-8244-4039-9100-06afee678557 /
sr0
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all, "dummy" is probably not best term - `procfs`, `sysfs` or `dev(tmp)fs` are far from being useless. Either use the `-t` (type) option for `mount` and feed it a comma separated list of filesystems you are interested in:

```
mount -t tmpfs,xfs
```

or use `grep` to filter what you want (probably `grep -v` to show what doesn't match):

```
mount | grep -Ev "(cgroup|proc|sysfs)"
```

Comment: Be sure to also exclude `tmpfs`.

Comment: @Jan that is arguable: many people use `tmpfs` as storage, especially on machines with lots of memory - and I'm not talking 8GB here, more like 0.25TB+ :) But even with "mere" 8GB it comes in handy.

Comment: Hadn't thought of that, you're right.

Answer (score 1):

`df` in GNU coreutils has a list of ignored filesystem types, but it doesn't contain many entries. For the most part, it eliminates filesystems that have a size of 0. This usually covers the ignored filesystem types anyway.

`mount` doesn't have direct access to the filesystem size. To get the same filtering, you would need to collate the output of `mount` with the output of `df` or some other tool to get the filesystem size.

Here's a way to get sorted output from `df` and `mount`, and sort and join it.

```
join -o 2.1,2.2,2.3,2.4,2.5,2.6,2.7,2.8,2.9 <(df -P | tail -n +2 | sort) <(mount | sort)
```

Here's another approach with a Python one-liner. (Perl is a lot better at such one-liners but doesn't have `statvfs` in its standard library.)

```
mount | python -c 'import os, sys; [sys.stdout.write(line) for (dev, line) in [(line.split(" ")[2], line) for line in sys.stdin.readlines()] if os.statvfs(dev).f_blocks]'
```